# react-select onChange how to access user input and not select option value?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm new to this library, I'm not sure if I missed something in the docs...

I'm trying to `console.log` the user's input through an `onChange` event (your average `onChange` that fires every time the input field changes). However the event only fires when a user selects an option, and the value that get's logged is the value of one of the select options, not the user input.

I'm guessing it's because it's more of a select option type of component, rather than an input component.
How do I go around implementing what I want here?

```
<Select onChange = {handleChange} options = {data} />

const handleChange = (e) => {
  console.log(e)
}
```

EXTRA NOTE:

My purpose for accessing the user input is, because my data array containst more than 7000 items, to change the data array to render less than 10 items according to use input, so that my app doesn't lag.